# NotificationListenerService alternative in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android

Is there any way to listen to notificstions(read their text) shown in notificstion bar in Xamarin?
I know that in AndroidStudio, we can use NotificationListenerService, but I can not find any Xamarin alternative.
Real example:
I recieve a Whatsapp message and get notified, I want my app to check if the message was sent by Emily- if so, do something...
Thanks for help and replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xamarin.Android` has a framework wrapper for `Android.Service.Notification.NotificationListenerService`.

```
[Register ("android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService", DoNotGenerateAcw = true, ApiSince = 18)]
public abstract class NotificationListenerService : Service
{
  ~~~
}
```

Just as in `Java`, it is an abstract class that you need to implement.

```
public class MyNotificationListenerService : NotificationListenerService
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    public override void OnNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
        ~~~~
    }

    public override void OnNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
        ~~~~
    }
}
```